# Update multiple rows in MySQL with checkboxes with jquery datatable php sql

Tags: jquery, datatables, rows

I was using simple multiple rows update using checkboxes,php and sql, but now i am moving to  jquery.datatables http://www.datatables.net/

I am not able to get checkbox values in it. Any one can tell me is there any method or i am doing any mistake ?

Following is method i am using :

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $id = "('" . implode( "','", $checkbox ) . "');" ;
    mysql_query ("update value1 from table where id in '$id'");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your update query is wrong have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html. You should also escape your vars to prevent sql injection. Or better use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: HHmm but i am not even getting  $checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the new version of data-tables and it fixed that.

Comment: Wow, 4 years since the original question and you just posted a solution! +1 for never giving up!